# Bluetooth dongle with support for A2DP and the AAC codec

Tags: audio, bluetooth, codec, aac, a2dp

I recently bought some Sony MDR-1RBT headphones which can be used via audio cable, but also via Bluetooth. They support BT 3.0 with A2DP and use SBC or AAC as codec.

Unfortunately they do not support APT-X, but they have been tested much better than the Sennheisers which do support APT-X.

So, now I am looking for a USB dongle to feed these headphones via Blueetooth. Thus I need a BT dongle that supports 3.0 or later, the A2DP profile and AAC. If the dongle would also support APT-X (for the future) that would be awesome.

Unfortunately I cannot find any dongle that satisifies these simple requirements.

Well, I wonder whether the codecs that are being supported depend on the hardware or actually only on the driver/software stack? I am using Win7 mainly.

So the questions are:
Can I buy any BT 3 stick that supports A2DP and can that be "convinced" to talk AAC by using the right software? Which BT software stack would do the job?

Any other recommendations?

Comment: There's one advertised on Outlaw Audio that supports aptX, AAC, and A2DP. According to the manual, it uses Bluetooth ver 4.1. https://www.outlawaudio.com/products/btr200d.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about AAC, but the list of AptX compatible dongles is here: http://www.csr.com/technology-solutions/av/audio-products-powered-by-csr-aptx/bluetooth-transmitter